# Can I migrate importing Features 6 code?

Tags: 7, migrations, features

I am attempting to migrate Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 using the migrate_d2d_ui module, but the cck fields are not coming over correctly.

Can I use the Drupal 6 Features module to generate code which can be imported by the Drupal 7 Features module?

Comment: No. They aren't compatible.

Comment: Thanks, Jaypan.  I was afraid that would be the case.  Otherwise, Features would be the perfect upgrade/migration tool.